# How to download file using selenium webdriver from a third website

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am automating a process wherein I should be able to login to  a website and download and rename the files automatically.

1. It should download only the csv files which are ending with '06'.
2. It should comapare the Report ID with Report Type. Example : If Report ID is  'XXXXXX06' and Report Type starts with "PAS' then it should rename the filename with XXXXXX06 PAS.csv and same goes If Report ID is  'XXXXXX06' and Report Type starts with "TAS' then it should rename the filename with XXXXXX06 TAS.csv

I am attaching the code. I am only unable to download and rename the file, rest all the functionalities are working fine. I think there is some issue in giving the xpath.

[image]

```
package package1;
import java.io.File;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.HashMap;

import java.util.List;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;


public class Test_new {

public static WebDriver setup() throws Exception

{
    String downloadFilepath = "E:\\HCA_Automation\\Files";
    System.out.println(downloadFilepath);
    HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);

    chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadFilepath);

    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

    options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);

    DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();

    cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);

    cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);

    //WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(cap);

    WebDriver wd;

    //String exepath=System.getProperty("user.dir") + "//chromedriver.exe";

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
            "C:\\Users\\sh370472\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32 (1)\\chromedriver.exe");

    return (wd= new ChromeDriver(cap));

    }


    public static void login(WebDriver wd) throws Throwable
    {
    wd.manage().window().maximize();
    wd.get("https://www.shipper-ml.com");
    wd.findElement(By.id("inpUserId")).sendKeys("XXXXXXXX");
    wd.findElement(By.id("inpPassword")).sendKeys("XXXXXXXXXXXX");
    wd.findElement(By.id("btnLogonLabel")).click();
    Thread.sleep(1000); 
}

public static void execute(WebDriver wd) throws Throwable{
    wd.get("https://www.shipper-ml.com/viewReports.do");  
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    List<WebElement> list= wd.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class='lcb']/tbody/tr/td/table[@class='ibody']/tbody/tr/td[contains(translate(text(),'0123456789'),'06')]/parent::tr/td[7]/a"));
    int i = 0;
    FileUtils.cleanDirectory(new File("E:\\HCA_Automation\\Files"));
    for (WebElement element:list)
    {
        i++;
        element.click();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println((element.findElement(By.xpath("(//table[@class='lcb']/tbody/tr/td/table[@class='ibody']/tbody/tr/td[contains(translate(text(), '0123456789'),'06')]/parent::tr/td[3])["+i+"]")).getText()).substring(0,2));
        String report_type = (element.findElement(By.xpath("(//table[@class='lcb']/tbody/tr/td/table[@class='ibody']/tbody/tr/td[contains(translate(text(), '0123456789'),'06')]/parent::tr/td[3])["+i+"]")).getText()).substring(0,2);

    } 
}


public static void tearDown(WebDriver wd) throws Throwable{
    wd.quit();
}



public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable 
{
    WebDriver wd = setup();
    login(wd);
    execute(wd);
    tearDown(wd);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    FileUtils.copyDirectory(new File("C:\\Users\\nea558\\Desktop\\New_Folder\\Files\\TAS\\"), new File( "\\\\zneugo1p17ecn02.bp1.ad.bp.com\\DataTransfer\\ETAP\\DropBoxes\\CATS\\01_Inbox"));

    //FileUtils.copyDirectory(new File("C:\\Users\\nea558\\Desktop\\New_Folder\\Files\\PAS\\"), new File("\\\\bp1xeuap2433\\aamon\\scheduler\\Handoffs\\paa\\itd\\process"));

}

}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="lc_ctrl258037362">
    <table id="ctrl258037362" cellspacing="0" width="845px" class="lc_nf" border="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="lcb" border="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table cellspacing="1" width="100%" class="ibody" border="0" cellpadding="0">
                                <colgroup>
                                    <col>
                                    <col>
                                    <col>
                                    <col>
                                    <col>
                                    <col>
                                    <col>
                                    <col>
                                </colgroup>
                                <tbody>
                                <tr class="header">
                                    <td>Report ID</td>
                                    <td>Version No.</td>
                                    <td>Report Type</td>
                                    <td>Contract</td>
                                    <td>Date Created</td>
                                    <td>Status</td>
                                    <td align="center">Excel</td>
                                    <td align="center">XML</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr onmouseover="high(this);" class="even" onmouseout="low(this);" style="">
                                    <td class="cl">19062006</td>
                                    <td class="cl">V1</td>
                                    <td class="cl">PAS ITD/EOD EX1 Allocation Statement</td>
                                    <td class="cl">ETAP</td>
                                    <td class="cl">21/06/2019 08:56</td>
                                    <td class="cl">Published</td>
                                    <td align="center" class="cl">
                                        <a href="/viewReports.do?ctrl=reportListForDownload&amp;action=DownloadReport&amp;param=0" target="_blank">
                                            <img vspace="0" align="absmiddle" border="0" src="images/buttons/excel.gif"></a></td>
                                    <td align="center" class="cl"><a href="/viewReports.do?ctrl=reportListForDownload&amp;action=DownloadXml&amp;param=0" target="_blank"><img
                                            vspace="0" align="absmiddle" border="0" src="images/buttons/document.gif"></a></td>
                                </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm unclear what you are asking, this may help https://ardesco.lazerycode.com/testing/webdriver/2012/07/25/how-to-download-files-with-selenium-and-why-you-shouldnt.html

Comment: @Ardesco, I have attached the screenshot.

Comment: So if I'm understanding this right you want to know how to write code to download a file, the above article will tell you how to do that.

Comment: @Ardesco, I have written the code already but I think I am giving wrong xpath. I am unable to frame the correct xpath. I need help in that.

Comment: In that case we need to see the markup of the page in question.  We can't calculate locators based upon screenshots.

Comment: Looking at the download code, I would really suggest you read the article above, I can think of multiple ways you could get failures/false positives with what you have written.

Comment: @Ardesco, Yes, but i am unable to post the html of the page here due to security concerns. If you can give me your personal mail id probably i can share it with you. I read the article, but the page in question doesn't have proper structure so xpath is the only option to download the files i guess.

Comment: If you can't post it on here, you can't share it with me either (because I could then post it on here).  I really don't see what security concern there is around showing the markup of table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195340/discussion-between-begginer-and-ardesco).

Comment: @Ardesco, I have added the html part. Can you please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

An XPath that will find the download link is as follows:

```
//table/descendant-or-self::tr[td[3][text()='PAS ITD/EOD EX1 Allocation Statement']]/td[7]/a
```

This finds a `<table>` element that contains a `<tr>` element that has a `<td>` element with a value of `PAS ITD/EOD EX1 Allocation Statement` and then routes you to `<td>` element in the same row that contains the download link.

To put this into code where you can tweak the report type value, you can use:

```
String reportTypeValue = "PAS ITD/EOD EX1 Allocation Statement"
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/descendant-or-self::tr[td[3][text()='" + reportTypeValue + "']]/td[7]/a")
```

***Edit***

Based on your comment you just got way more complicated, I now have:

```
//table/descendant-or-self::tr[td[1][substring(text(), string-length(text()) - string-length('06') + 1)]][td[3][text()='PAS ITD/EOD EX1 Allocation Statement']]/td[7]/a
```

This will find a `<table>` element that contains a `<tr>` element that has a `<td>` element with a value of `PAS ITD/EOD EX1 Allocation Statement` and a `<td>` element that ends with the value `06`.  It then routes you to `<td>` element in the same row that contains the download link.

XPath 1.0 doesn't support ends-with hence this block:

```
substring(text(), string-length(text()) - string-length('06') + 1)]
```

This is working out the length of the text node and the length of the string  that you are searching for and using the substring functionality to ensure the last x characters match.

To put it into a new block of code that you can use to tweak the report type value and the report ID you can do:

```
String reportID = "06"
String reportTypeValue = "PAS ITD/EOD EX1 Allocation Statement"
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/descendant-or-self::tr[td[1][substring(text(), string-length(text()) - string-length('" + reportID + "') + 1)]][td[3][text()='" + reportTypeValue + "']]/td[7]/a")
```

Comment: The files should be downloaded based on the Report ID and Report Type both. I cannot download the file based on one field only because if you see the screenshot which I have attached, the Report Type field is not unique. I want to download the files which has Report ID as 06 at the ending.

Comment: it is downloading the first file in the queue and not the file which has Report ID ending with '06'

Comment: can you help me please